# Create Close-up Half Circle in HTML CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, figma

I was ask to create half circle-like design for my project in html css , its look like this :

[Figma Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEsk4.png) but it really ""zoomed"in.

i tried to make it and the closest i could look like this :
[My Closest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3OOK.png)

with this code :

```css
.semi-circle {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 150px 150px;
  /* border-radius: 0 0 150px 150px;  */
  background-color: #0E47A1;
}
```

```html
<div class="semi-circle"></div>
```

what can i tweak and how to make it like the designed one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres some idea for you. you can set it to transform then rotate it at the same time put a fake div at the top so you can cover all remaining blue. Let me know.

```css
body {background-color:lightgrey;}

.semi-circle { 
  height: 200px; 
  width: 200px; 
  border-radius : 50%;             
  background-color: #0E47A1; 
  margin-top:0px;
  transform: scale(1.5) rotateX(105deg);  
  overflow:hidden;
  align-items:center;
  margin-left:50px;

} 

.box { 
  width: 300px;
  height: 800px;
  border:1px solid gray;
  background-color:white;
  }
 
.blue {
  background-color:#0E47A1;
  height:100px;
  }

.whitebox {
  width:220px;
  height:40px;
  line-height:1;
  margin:0 auto;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 2px gray;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
  border-radius:20px;
  position:absolute;
  top:120px;
  left:40px;
  background-color:white;
  }
```

```html
<body> 
  
 <div>Home</div>
 
  <div class="box">
  <div class="blue">
   <div class="semi-circle"></div> 
    <div class="whitebox">Hello Visitors!
     <span>this is the hidden text......</span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: woah, i didnt think to do that, cover it with fake div. thankyou ill try it !

Answer (score 0):

I have used `::after` to create the effect, you can change the `height` get desired curve.

```css
.curve{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.curve::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius:50%;
  background: blue;
  width:500px;
  height:300px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="curve"></div>
```

Comment: oh , i just known there is ::after properties. thankyou  ill learn deeper on that

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the example. It is responsive and will fit like that on any screen.

```css
.semi-circle {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  height: 150%;
  width: 150%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* border-radius: 0 0 150px 150px;  */
  background-color: #0E47A1;
  position: absolute;
  top: -90%;
  left: -22.5%;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="semi-circle"></div>
```